# Codeigniter 2.2.2 dbforge produces DEFAULT '' NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
<?php defined("BASEPATH") or exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Migration_Create_clients_categories_table extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'auto_increment' => TRUE,
            ),
            'parent_id' => array(
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'default' => NULL,
                'null' => TRUE,
            ),
        ));
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);

        $this->dbforge->create_table('clients_categories');
    }

    public function down() 
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('clients_categories');
    }
}
```

After running the migration i get this error:

> Error Number: 1067, Invalid default value for 'parent_id'
>   `parent_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '' NULL

The thing is that i don't know why dbforge produces `\`DEFAULT '' NULL\ since it should be just `\`DEFAULT NULL. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a limitation on the _process_fields() function in the CI database driver. It says:

```
if (array_key_exists('DEFAULT', $attributes))
{
    $sql .= ' DEFAULT \''.$attributes['DEFAULT'].'\'';
}
```

...so those quotes are hard-coded into the MySQL call.

HOWEVER (radical edit to what I originally answered): if a field is NULLable and no default value is set, MySQL will make the default NULL by default, if you see what I mean.

From the manual:

> If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows:
>
> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.
>
> ...

So the fact that you can't do that using the migration or dbForge is basically fine.